# XP orders files backwards

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Windows XP sorts everything alphebetically by name, except that it does it backwards. As it folders are always at the end and then ordered from Z-A. This is not only in Windows Explorer (which is easy to fix via the sort option) but also in dialogs when I click to browse for a file. For example in Firefox, when I click to upload a file, it shows everything ordered from Z-A and I need to move to the end to move to the next folder.

I would like them to be ordered from A-Z with folders at the beginning. Does anyone know how to remedy this permanently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the sort order in one folder to ascending again and then apply the current setting to all folders in the Folder settings.

Answer (score 0):

Set the the **View** to **Details** and click the **Name** column header to reverse the order:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't fix it permanently as far as I can tell.
Thank you for the help though, I especially appreciate the screenshot.

Comment: certainly works permanently for uploads in Firefox. if the changes don't stick, you should also increase the BagMRU value in the registry to 5000 (XP by default only remembers settings for 400 folders, which is next to nothing).